# Tokenizing Strings

Tags: vba, ms-word, tokenize

I have around 100 rows of text that I want to tokenize, which are alike the following:

```
<word> <unknown number of spaces and tabs> <number>
```

I am having trouble finding tokenize functions with VBA. What would be the easiest method to tokenize such strings in VBA?

Comment: Where are you taking the strings from? If they are in the actual Word document, you could use Word's built-in search and replace function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could read line by line and use the split function to split the word and number by space. I vaguely remeber VBA has the split function.

I got the following link by searching in google. Not sure which version of office you are using.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155763(office.10).aspx

This link has the split function.

Comment: I have managed to split the row into an array of string, let's say it's called hello(). The valid contents are in the first and last entries of hello(). How would I figure out the sizes of the array for me to address the first and last entry of the array, as the array's size is variable.

Comment: you can use ubound(array) to get the count of elements. You can get the first entry by array(0) & last entry by array(ubound(array)). Split returns a 1 dimensional array. So, myarray = split("hello world", " ") debug.print myarray(0) dim elementCount as integer elementCount = ubound(myarray) debug.print myarray(elementCount).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Split()` method or for more complex matches, you can use the `"vbscript.regexp"` object:

```
Sub NewRegex()
    Dim reg
    Dim matches, match, tmpStr As String

    Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    tmpStr = "blah bla ...."

    With reg
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "your regex pattern goes here"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = reg.Execute(tmpStr)

    For Each match In matches
        MsgBox match
    Next mt

End Sub
```

Here's a tutorial on using regex from VBA: [Using Regular Expressions (RegExp) in Excel](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=68)

Comment: Dang. Another perfectly good reason why I should be learning REGEX. Grr. :)

Answer (score 0):

VBA split function right from MS's page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155763(office.10).aspx